# SQL как задать два условия для выбора данных?

Tags: android, sql

Как мне добавить второе условие для выбора.

Второе условие: `column_parent = ?`, `String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { parent }`

**Мой код:**

```
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { key.toString() };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SUBTASKS, null,
            "column_key = ?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На место каждого нового знака вопроса в условии, будет подставлен следующий аргумент из массива `selectionArgs` :

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { key.toString() , parent};
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SUBTASKS, null,
        "column_key = ? AND column_parent = ?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```